# How can I obtain the parent of the path inside an URL object in Java?

Tags: java, url, jakarta-ee, directory

I have the following problem in a Java application

By this statment I retrieve the current location of my application:

```
URL location = Main.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
```

So for example my **location** contains a path like: **/C:/Projects/edi-sta/out/production/edi-sta/**

Ok, how can I easilly obtain the parent path?

For example, considering the previous path, how can I obtain the ****/C:/Projects/edi-sta/out/production/** path (that is the direct parent of the last **edi-sta/** folder) ?

Java provide me something that do it out of the box or have I to implement a string manipulation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `URI#resolve(String)` to get a `URL` that points to the parent:

```
URL parentUrl = location.toURI().resolve("..").toURL();  // .. for parent
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [getParentFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getParentFile%28%29) method from standard Java.

Comment: I can't use getParentFile() on the URL object. What have I to do to use it?